# Bracket identification, 1x2 plate with 2x2 sideways overhang

Tags: part-identification

I would like to know the name of these pieces.

[image]

The grey one (not the one with the towball socket)

(edit: found, it is 6009014 "Bracket 1 x 2 - 2 x 2") and the green one, they're similar but the grey one have the studs on the "inner" part, I think.

Edit: Found the grey one, still need the green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pieces are [Bracket 1 x 2 - 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44728#T=C) and [Bracket 1 x 2 - 2 x 2 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99207#T=C). The grey piece is actually the inverted one.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers should be printed underneath, then it's just a matter of finding the right colour e.g. look up part 44728 on BrickSet.com and you get http://brickset.com/parts/design-44728, then I'd say the right colour was dark green giving you http://brickset.com/parts/4212471